# Can not find test class 'junit.test.DepartmentTest' in project 'jyxxw'

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

when I run configurations, but my Eclipse shows that

> Can not find test class 'junit.test.DepartmentTest' in project 'jyxxw'

Comment: yes,and but failed to run configuration..

Answer (score 0):

This is a message that Eclipse gives when it doesn't recognize the class as being a test class.  Do you have any @Test annotations in your class?  (I realize that sounds like a silly question, but they could be in the superclass.  In which case Eclipse doesn't see them.)

Can you try replacing your test code temporarily with a really simple test and see if the error goes away?

```
package junit.test;
import org.junit.*;
public class DepartmentTest {
  @Test public void myTest() {}
}
```

If this works, you can see what's missing in your class.  If it doesn't work, it is likely a classpath issue.